# issuing and validating certificate with AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-acm

Is it possible to use the AWS SDK to issue and validate a certificate using CNAME records? I can request a certificate using the SDK but AWSCertificateManager.getCertificate won't return pending certificates and AWSCertificateManager.listCertificates only returns certificate summaries.

I want to use the AWS SDK to get the expected CNAME and then insert the expected CNAME records using the AWS SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which language SDK you are referring to, but they are all similar since they call the same underlying API.  The action you are looking for is `describeCertificate()`, which provides the information needed for domain validation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ACM.html#describeCertificate-property

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/describe-certificate.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeCertificate.html

Comment: It's for Java and yes I think you're right - Google failed me but I guess I shouldn't be surprised as all the SDKs and accompanying documentation seem to be auto-generated and a little scant on in-depth information.